# running a function to load csv data into the DB via Django

Tags: django

This should be like nobrainer question., but it intrigues me.

I want to load a roster of countries into the database and yes, I know I could easily do it directly by importing the csv either in mysql or postgres, and I could also write the code snippet into the console (very inconvenient) and would work fine, but I wonder how you do it in django. Because, if I have this:

```
def loadccountries():
    with open(uploads/countries.csv) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            _,created = countries.objects.get_or_create(
                name = row[0]
            )
```

then, where do I place that code?, in the views? if yes, then, how do I make that function alone run? I cannot see myself creating artificial urls in urls.py and an html page so that I can call the view from the URL etc. Dont vote me down, I am struggling not to go below 23 score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) which calls your `loadcountries` method.

This would allow you run:

```
manage.py loadcountries
```